# Just getting to grips with CSS. Can some tell me why my content div is slightly poking out the right edge?

Tags: html, css

Here is the link.

http://jsfiddle.net/8X4UE/

```
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
    <title>Project One</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="header">
        <p>#Project One</p>
    </div>

    <ul class="nav">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">FAQs</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Forum</a></li>

    </ul>
    <div class="content">
        <p>Content goes here!</p>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
/* The CSS */

body {
    margin: 0 20%;
    background-color: #333333;
}

.header{

    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #336699;

}

.header p{
    margin-left: 1em;
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    color: #e2e2e2;
}

.nav{
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.nav li{
    float: left;
}

.nav li a{
    display: block;
    padding: 8px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #069;
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.nav li a:hover{
    color: #c00;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.content {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #FFFFCC;
    margin: 0;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    clear: both;
}
```

I can't understand why it is just pipping out like that. It seems if I remove the padding/float it almost sorts it, but then leaves a yellow border across all three sections.

I'd like any general advice with my coding so far if you have any too. I want to nip bad habits in the bud asap.

Comment: hi is the border play important part with your layout in `.content` ?

Answer (score 6):

Remove `width:100%`.

When you give a `100%` width, you have to take in consideration that the border has a width as well, so `100% width + 1 pixel left border + 1 pixel right border = the right pipping`

### CSS3's box sizing

Like previously mentioned, setting a 100% width for a div, means giving it the actually 100% width of the parent, without taking in consideration that this div might have a border, or padding.

So, if the parent has a 200px width, and the child has a 100% width, and a padding of 5px, and a border of 1px, the resulting width of the div will be:

```
200px + 1px + 1px + 5px + 5px = 212 px.
```

To avoid this, CSS3 brought a new property called **box-sizing**.

Using box-sizing, the div will have a 100% width, while containing the width of the border and any padding.

```
box-sizing:border-box;
-moz-box-sizing:border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
```

Now the div will have exactly a 200px width, which includes the padding and the border width.

Comment: I'll +1 if you add info about `box-sizing`

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. In this case is my width 100% actually doing anything?

Comment: @JMCharter the div has `display:block;`, means it will automatically have the full width of the parent element, so you're `width:100%;` is useless.

Answer (score 0):

The content is appearing to the right because `borders` count as 'content'.

Your problem is here:

```
.content {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #FFFFCC;
    margin: 0;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    clear: both;
}
```

If you replace it for

```
.content {
    ...
    border: 0px solid #ccc;
    ...
}
```

Then it doesn't poke. As the other answer mentions, removing the width also does the trick (and it's exactly what you want).

Comment: Specifically, borders and padding ADD to your width. So 100% width is added to. Ironically if you leave the width off of your div, it sorts itself out.

Comment: Setting the border-width to 0 seems a little counter-productive if the OP *wants* the border.

Comment: Edited. It's one of the reasons why it happens. The OP might need the width.

Comment: In that case, `box-sizing: border-box`.

Comment: I see. Thanks, so this confirms my idea that width, in this case, is doing nothing for me? Cheers for the help.

Comment: @JMCharter No, in your case it's not necessary :)